# R postgres connection to remote survey error in RS-DBI driver

Tags: r, postgresql, connection

i cannot for the life of me get postgres connection a remote postgres db.

```
"Error in postgresqlNewConnection(drv, ...) : 
  RS-DBI driver: (could not connect"
```

I have RPostgreSQL installed, i have postgres running in the background, my macbook is up to date 10.12.5 macOS sierra.

and still cannot connect

```
  drv <- dbDriver("RPostgreSQL")
 > con <- dbConnect(drv, host=hostName, 
 +                  port=portName,
+                  dbname=databaseName, 
+                  user=userName, 
+                  password=passwordName)
Error in postgresqlNewConnection(drv, ...) : 
  RS-DBI driver: (could not connect
```

notably..i CAN connect with all the same credentials via postico app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using Windows and here is the code that worked well for me:
Something I thought was really weird that I needed both RPostgreSQL and RPostgres. I tried using only RPostgreSQL or RPostgres and failed with the error you got or something else. But this following order is necessary and worked.

```
install.packages("RPostgreSQL")
require(RPostgreSQL)
install.packages("RPostgres")
require(RPostgres)
install.packages("DBI")
require(DBI)

#Create a connection
con <- dbConnect(RPostgres::Postgres(),
                 dbname = "REMOTE_DB_NAME",
                 host = "xx-redshift-xx.yyy.com",
                 port = "XXXX",
                 user = "****", password = "****")

dbListTables(con)
```

Let me know if you run into issues.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem. I ended up using the [`RPostgres`](https://github.com/rstats-db/RPostgres) package.

*Disclaimer*: I wan't able to install the package by following the git_hub instructions exactly;

Here is what I did to successfully install it on windows:

1) Install `Rtools` following the instructions [here](https://github.com/stan-dev/rstan/wiki/Install-Rtools-for-Windows):

2) Install `devtools`:

```
install.packages("devtools")
```

3) Install `Rcpp` and `DBI` as the instruction:

```
devtools::install_github("RcppCore/Rcpp")
devtools::install_github("rstats-db/DBI")
```

4) Download the `RPostgres` source file on [github](https://github.com/rstats-db/RPostgres) by clicking *clone and download*; Extract it to a folder;

5) Install `RPostgres` from the source folder:

```
install.packages("path_to_downloads/Downloads/RPostgres-master/", repos = NULL, type="source")
```

Comment: i can't seem to install it. feel like it was built for an earlier version of R. i'm using
                         
platform       x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0   
arch           x86_64                      
os             darwin13.4.0                
system         x86_64, darwin13.4.0        
minor          3.2                         
year           2016                        
month          10                          
day            31                          
version.string R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31)
nickname       Sincere Pumpkin Patch

Comment: Not 100% for sure. I have the same system configurations as yours. One trick that I found that helps is install Rcpp in the normal way `install.packages("Rcpp"); devtools::install_github("rstats-db/DBI"); devtools::install_github("rstats-db/RPostgres")`