# R (4.2.1) crashes to desktop when trying to download from PostgreSQL/Postgis

Tags: r, postgresql, version, postgis

Some code that worked (still works flawlessly in R 4.1.3) crashes to desktop in 4.2.1.

This only happens when I try to open a table which contains a geometry column. If I select only non-geometry columns everything works fine *but as soon as I try to get the geometry column*, R unceremoniously dies.
(The PostgreSQL DB is definetly working with Postgis.)

I've tried loading the data with:

```
DBI::dbReadTable()
RPostgreSQL::dbReadTable()
RPostgres::dbReadTable()
rpostgis::dbReadDataFrame()
RJDBC::dbReadTable()
sf::st_read() ## st_read(conn, query) is how it was coded in the first place.

## I also tried dbSendQuery()

conn <- dbConnect(drv = drv,
                   dbname = db2,
                   host = host_db1,
                   port = db_port,
                   user = tolower(Sys.info()[[7]]), ## capital letters may cause failed login
                   password = pw)
query = paste("SELECT * FROM some_table") # this worked in R 4.1.3 but doesn't in 4.2.1

conn %>% st_read(query = query)
```

The PC I'm working on runs Windows 10.

I ran out of ideas what to test, since there is no error message. I can access the data as per usual via dbvis as well as any non-geometry column via queries. So I am pretty sure it isn't a syntax error or a system error. Would be happy for any advice (other than "just use R 4.1.3").

EDIT:
ression-user.log:

```
2022-08-09T06:24:07.254357Z [rsession-user] ERROR CLIENT EXCEPTION (rsession-user): (TypeError) : Cannot read property 'O' of null;|||org/rstudio/studio/client/workbench/views/source/editors/text/AceEditor.java#4509::setScrollSpeed|||org/rstudio/studio/client/workbench/views/source/editors/text/AceEditorMonitor.java#46::monitor|||org/rstudio/studio/client/workbench/views/source/editors/text/AceEditorMonitor.java#70::execute|||com/google/gwt/core/client/impl/SchedulerImpl.java#140::execute|||com/google/gwt/core/client/impl/Impl.java#306::apply|||com/google/gwt/core/client/impl/Impl.java#345::entry0|||rstudio-0.js#-1::eval|||com/google/gwt/cell/client/AbstractEditableCell.java#41::viewDataMap|||Client-ID: 33e600bb-c1b1-46bf-b562-ab5cba070b0e|||User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0  Win64  x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) QtWebEngine/5.12.8 Chrome/69.0.3497.128 Safari/537.36
```

Comment: Can you set up a `crash dump` on Windows 10 (do you have admin?). I'm on linux, so... but mine go to something like /var/whoopsie when enabled.

Comment: Sadly i am not admin. Will ask the admin  responsible to let me try though! Thx

Comment: @Chris i couldn't get a crash dump yet although i fopund a coresponding rsession error: `2022-08-09T06:24:07.254357Z [rsession-user] ERROR CLIENT EXCEPTION (rsession-user): (TypeError) : Cannot read property 'O' of null;|||org/rstudio/studio/client/workbench/views/source/editors/text/AceEditor.java`. also i noticed that it is not generally impossible to download geometries from a postgis DB. it works for `postgis 3.1.5` but doesn't for `postgis 2.5.1`. I assume R >= 4.0 has a problem with this

Comment: Where to begin? This [rpostgis discussion](https://github.com/mablab/rpostgis/issues/25) put it over on `sf::st_write`, and while concerning `sf::st_read` this [sf discussion](https://github.com/r-spatial/sf/issues/1967) says the matter is being noticed, and appears you're the only one with an error report so you might append your r-session user log there, with all your various versions...

Comment: @Chris thanks for that comment. Those were interesting reads (especially the sf discussion). I just found the error (being hidden in an old [DBI update](https://dbi.r-dbi.org/news/) ). DBI 0.6 to be precise. `dbDriver("PostgreSQL")` is depreciated which is mentioned nowhere else I could find. The problem can be solved using  `RPostgres::Postgres()` instead of `dbDriver()`. Interestingly this also gets rid of a `dbplyr` warning message concerning old code. Should I raise this in your mentioned [github topic](https://github.com/r-spatial/sf/issues/1967). I think it may solve the posters problem.

Comment: I was wrestling through all that a couple of hours ago, bang head on wall, expect different result and came across [SOF RPostgres::Postgres()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44401454/r-postgres-connection-to-remote-survey-error-in-rs-dbi-driver) accepted answer, but I first had to do some psql \conninfo to get my setup, that hadn't made it to my notes. And, yes, your depricated research and resolution are useful to post there. They'll be happier.

Comment: @Chris very nice! i didn't find that one. would have made my life **much** easier. too bad i cant award points on comments.