# How can I solve Postgresql SCRAM authentication problem?

Tags: postgresql, authentication, libpq

I am getting an error after moving the project to production. The error is as follows while running with production server

> pg_connect(): Unable to connect to PostgreSQL server: SCRAM
> authentication requires libpq version 10 or above.

Here is my PostgreSQL version:

**Development Version :**

PostgreSQL 11.5 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 4.8.5 20150623
(Red Hat 4.8.5-36), 64-bit

**Production Version :**

PostgreSQL 11.5 (EnterpriseDB Advanced Server 11.5.12) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-36), 64-bit

Comment: You probably have an old libpq on your *client* computer

Comment: @ a_horse_with_no_name is there duplicate  libpq file?

Comment: How should we know? The  "installed" version refers to the server, not to the client (where your program runs)

Comment: I am already check both version between development postgre version and production server by running select version() 
the result I post in my question.Please read my question carefully you will get both version installed

Comment: You need to check the version on the **client** (where you  run your code), not the server

Comment: Production server version:(client where I run the program)
PostgreSQL 11.5 (EnterpriseDB Advanced Server 11.5.12) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-36), 64-bit

Comment: Development Server:
PostgreSQL 11.5 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-36), 64-bit

Comment: sudo amazon-linux-extras enable postgresql10 - this has saved me

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Your application uses an API that is linked with the PostgreSQL client C library `libpq`.

The version of that library must be 9.6 or older, and SCRAM authentication was introduced in v10.

Upgrade `libpq` **on the application end** and try again.

If you don't need `scram-sha-256` authentication, you can revert to `md5`:

- set `password_encryption = md5` in `postgresql.conf`
- change the authentication method to `md5` in `pg_hba.conf`
- reload PostgreSQL
- change the password of the user to get an MD5 encrypted password

Comment: do you have link tutorial related your answer to upgrade my library to version 10 ?

Comment: How did you install `libpq` on the client machine? Probably you have to repeat the steps with the new version.

Comment: I think it's installed when  instaling HTTPD webserver on linux.

Comment: If it comes from the operating system distribution, perhaps you can upgrade the operating system? It might be easier to install the packages from the PostgreSQL web page though. But then you probably also need a new version of the module that is linke with `libpq`.

Comment: Or you can revert to `md5`. See my extended answer.

Comment: thank you @Laurenz Albe. my client try to update postgresql with higher version and my problem solved.

Comment: can you please tell me or give me a reference to upgrade `libpq` on Windows please? I searched it and not found it. help

Comment: because I've change the password encryption to `md5` as you said but still didn't work

Comment: @AlifRamdani You can use the installer from EnterpriseDB, or you can grab `libpq.dll` and its dependent libraries from the ZIP file.

Comment: I my case it was the compiled UMN Mapserver as a Client trying to access the new Postgres. When Upgrading to newer Version the error went away. Thanks @LaurenzAlbe

Comment: Switching from conan package libpq/9.6.19 to libpq/10.14 solved this for me

Answer (score 94):

For those on M1-Based macs who are currently seeing this issue in docker - there appears to a bug upstream in libpg that's building against the wrong library version on ARM.

Until it's fixed, a workaround is to (at a performance hit) is to just [run it via rosetta](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/mac/apple-silicon/).

`export DOCKER_DEFAULT_PLATFORM=linux/amd64`, and re-build your images.

You'll get the latest version of libpq, and things should Just Work.

Ref: https://github.com/psycopg/psycopg2/issues/1360

Comment: Thanks for this tip. your diagnosis is correct. tho because i use docker-compose i chose to use this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/69636473/80353 instead

Comment: Good workaround, but I can confirm this now works on native containers, using pyscopg2==2.9.3 as suggested by @ihm in another answer.

Comment: This works, but tanks performance vs native.  doing `sysbench cpu --threads=2 run` native vs in qemu showed a native score of 22,415,068 vs 506 in qemu.

`export DOCKER_DEFAULT_PLATFORM=linux/amd64` 
 
`docker run -it ubuntu bash`

`apt update` 

`apt install sysbench` 

`sysbench cpu --threads=2 run` 

vs 

`brew install sys bench` 
`sysbench cpu --threads=2 run`

Comment: This becomes not only a *performance hit*, but unacceptable if you try running anything more serious than a data base.

Comment: What I did was to use aarch64 and just copy right version of libpq while building Dockerfile. Interestingly enough, it works correctly for MacOS M1 version, it does not work for Dockerfile within MacOS M1.

`RUN cp \`find /usr/lib/ -name libpq\*.so\` \`find /app -name libpq\*\`
`
This works for me and keeps running native on M1.

Comment: You can also downgrade from postgres alpine-14 to alpine-13.3. For me that fixed it :)

Comment: This issue was fixed in `psycopg2` version `2.9.6`, so updating to that version should fix it now. :)

Answer (score 53):

I ran into this while running a `python:3.9` docker image where I had installed `psycopg2-binary==2.9.3`. Installing `psycopg2==2.9.3` instead resolved it for me.

Comment: This solved it for me on M1 / silicone

Comment: Same issue on bare Ubuntu, installing psycopg2 in production instead of psycopg2-binary fixed it.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Running an M1 on Rosetta is unacceptable if you require other more performance-heavy software in your container.

Comment: did you install psycopg2-binary 2.9.3 on your docker container? i can install it just fine locally but it fails every time when building the docker image

Comment: This also worked for me on Docker and Apple M1.

Comment: Great solution, worked for me on Docker and Apple M1

Comment: Works like a charm for M1. I also had to install `libpq-dev` but it was a clear error when I ran `docker-compose build`

Comment: We switched to JDBC driver in Tableau - problem solved

Answer (score 32):

For Amazon linux users:

```
$ sudo yum install -y amazon-linux-extras
```

then re install the postgres client again

```
$ sudo amazon-linux-extras install postgresql10
```

Then the main part install the python package in my case it was (psycopg2) reinstall it

```
$ pip3 install --force-reinstall psycopg2==2.9.3
```

specification:
python3.8.9

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks! One small remark: `ppsycopg2==2.9.3` instead of `ppsycopg2==2.93`

Answer (score 24):

I used to get an error ***SCRAM authentication requires libpq version 10 or above***  when running `php artisan migrate` in `laravel 8`. Then I fixed it as follows: Change authentication from `scram-sha-256` to `md5`, then `reset your password` and `restart the postgresql-x64-13 service` and here are step by step:

1. **Step 1**: Find file `postgresql.conf` in `C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\13\data` then set `password_encryption = md5`
2. **Step 2**: Find file `pg_hba.conf` in `C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\13\data` then change all `METHOD` to `md5`
3. **Step 3**: Open `command line (cmd,cmder,git bash...)` and run `psql -U postgres` then enter your password when installed postgres sql
4. Step 4: Then change your password by run `ALTER USER postgres WITH PASSWORD 'new-password'` in command line
5. Final: Restart service `postgresql-x64-13` in your `Service`.

Comment: For step 4, please remember to have ";" at the end of the line. It caused me half a day to figure it out. Successful run will return "ALTER ROLE" in the psql window

Comment: Also, I found that depending on different machines, I had to actually use a different password in step 3, and restart my computer instead for step 5

Comment: steps worked on v16

Answer (score 7):

If you want to keep the scram-sha-256 for security. You need to update your client postgreSQL libraries, due to `php-pgsql` default version does not support it.

**CentOS/Rhel/Rocky**

```
yum install https://download.postgresql.org/pub/repos/yum/reporpms/EL-7-x86_64/pgdg-redhat-repo-latest.noarch.rpm
yum install postgresql13
```

This will update the server/client libpq in order to keep using scram-sha-256

Comment: This works for me, and by the way, it's postgresql14 now.  yum install postgresql14

Comment: this worked on centos 7

Comment: This worked on RHEL7 with PostgreSQL 9.2 *client only* with these extra steps:

1. Clean away the 9.2 client: `yum remove postgresql`. 2. Add the 14.10 client: `yum install postgresql14` leaving you with `psql` 14.10 and presumably matching underlying libpq.

Answer (score 7):

This issue still affects m1 macs running `python:3.10.*` docker containers (based off aarch64 Debian 11). Solution for me was to install `psycopg2` (build from source) instead of `psycopg2-binary` which is advised for production anyways:

```
pip install psycopg2
```

The python container has all the build dependencies already (like gcc). A more production appropriate container most likely won't have these https://www.psycopg.org/docs/install.html#build-prerequisites

Answer (score 5):

Based on answer by @meijsermans, I changed the requirements.txt for django:

```
#psycopg2-binary>=2.9.3
psycopg2>=2.9.5
```

and it worked without the SCRAM error!

Also tried with and without `platform: linux/arm64` in docker.compose, didn't solve the problem.

Tried `platform: linux/amd64` and had some unrelated errors (mainly "exec /bin/sh: exec format error")
Using `postgres:14.5` image in postgres container and `python:3.10.7` image for django

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33444842)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 3):

I find 2 solutions. I didn't try local, solutions are for docker container.

Preliminary information:
According to the main image we defined at the beginning of the Dockerfile, our libq versions may differ. It is explained with examples in the answer given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70167233/11681124).

If you want to know your libq version used in your docker-image, you can do the following, respectively.

- After docker-compose run

  `docker-compose exec <app_name_in_docker-compose_file> sh`

  `python`

  `import psycopg2`

  `print(psycopg2.extensions.libpq_version())`

If you're getting an error, you'll probably see a number like 90xxx here.

Solutions:

- First basic one. I used 'python:3.9-slim-buster' at docker and I've got error. Change base image name to 'python:3.9.6-alpine3.14'
- The second solution is to build the psycopg2 file and install libq and other dependencies. [For this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70578039/11681124), add the following commands to the dockerfile.

> RUN apt update -y && apt install -y build-essential libpq-dev

> RUN pip3 install psycopg2-binary --no-binary psycopg2-binary

Answer (score 3):

All the answers that are suggesting that password encryption should be reverted back to `md5` are forgetting that PostgreSQL changed its default password encryption from `md5` to `scram-sha-256` for security reasons.
The issue then is those client applications that fail to use this modern encryption method. The `libpq` file that ships with PostgreSQL version 10 and above is fine. Just change your client applications if you can so that you use only the ones that support this new method.

For instance, For a long time I was using a package called `RPostgreSQL` that allows users to connect to a PostgreSQL database from `R`. Turns out that package doesn't support `scram-sha-256`. I have now replaced it with its modern equivalent called `rpostgres`. Problem solved, everybody happy now!

Comment: Thanks for sharing the solution, works fine to me, using this package (rpostgres). Cheers

Answer (score 2):

The following `docker-compose` snippet worked for me:

```
command: postgres -c password_encryption=md5
environment:
  [...]
  POSTGRES_INITDB_ARGS: "--auth-local=md5"
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Had this issue and fixed it by switching from the binary version of `psycopg2` to `psycopg2 = "^2.9.3"`

Comment: This worked for me but I didn't need to pin the version, just change to the non-binary package.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to previous answers, this was resolved in my case too when I **switched from `psycopg2-binary` to `psycopg2`**.

Use `pip install psycopg2` in your environment. This resolves the issue for ubuntu based systems.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more mundane answer, but this is what happened to me so I'll add it here.

I got this error when I tried to start PostgreSQL 9.4. I realized I already had PostgreSQL 11 running - it started automatically with my computer. Once I stopped version 11, I was able to start version 9.4. They can't listen on a port already in use, and both had the same port set. But I'm not sure exactly why the misleading error wording.

Answer (score 0):

Found this problem installing on a ubuntu 22.04 image with python3.10 on Mac M1.
What worked for me was installing the psycopg2 package as root rather than with `--user` - then the specific user can use the package.

Looks like the `--user` install puts an incorrectly linked libpq at
`/home/<user...>/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/psycopg2_binary.libs/libpq-d97d8807.so.5.9`

If you have another `pip install --user` process kicking about after this, and it installs psycopg2 again under the `.local` path, just remove that from `.local/lib/python3.x/site-packages/psycopg2*`

Answer (score 0):

1. Use vi (or other editor) to replace scram-sha-256 with md5 in the file postgresql.conf and post_hba.conf ; location of the files depends on your local set up. After this step 1 you may (most likely) continue to have the issue of authentication error. This is bcos the hash of password in DB still uses scram encryption. We will solve in the next few steps.
2. Restart postgresql server. This command depends on your server setup as well.
3. Reload DB and verify. Login with postgres id: `sudo -u postgres sql`

Reload (under the psql console):

```
SELECT pg_reload_conf();
```

Check Encryption:

```
SHOW password_encryption;
SELECT * FROM pg_hba_file_rules();
```

4. Reset password for user account (within the psql consol). This step will flush a new hash for the password under md5 to replace the existing scram hash of the user password.

   \password user_id

Then you can run a test of DB connection with psycopg2, as well as sqlalchemy.

This solves my problem in the way i can understand, being aware that md5 is less ideal an encryption method than scram-sha-256 but recompile the package to meet the requirement of psycopg2 is a pain in a**. So i would switch back to md5 first then when the package are all ready then change it to scram encryption.

Reference: [PostgreSQL downgrade password encryption from SCRAM to md5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67265537/postgresql-downgrade-password-encryption-from-scram-to-md5)

Answer (score 0):

I am a php-fpm docker user on Mac OS, neither the plateform env exports nor adding the directive to the `dockerfile/docker-compose.yml` succeded. On the other hand, switching postgres to md5 was a solution i wished to avoid. Besides, using `apt-get` inside the container resulted in too many dependency errors. What worked for me was just upgrading `php-fpm` to the latest version, rebuild the container then `apt-get` brought a `libpq >= 10` version

Actually my dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM --platform=linux/amd64 php:7.4-fpm
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y \
        librabbitmq-dev \
        libssh-dev \
        libpq-dev  \
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I use MacOS, and download the Postgres.app from this [link](https://postgresapp.com/downloads.html), can solve this problem：

**`SQLSTATE[08006] [7] SCRAM authentication requires qlibpq version 10 or above`**

Answer (score -1):

I noticed using later postgres database docker images - **postgres:14.x-alpine**
I got this error.

If feasible - you can downgrade to an older image that doesn't have these extra protections

```
version: '3.8'
services:


  db:
    image: postgres:9-alpine
    restart: always
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'
    volumes: 
      - db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
```

Answer (score -2):

```
RUN apt-get -y update \
    && apt-get install -y build-essential gettext libpq-dev\
    && apt-get install -y wkhtmltopdf\
    && apt-get install -y gdal-bin\
    && apt-get install -y libgdal-dev\
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends software-properties-common\
    && apt-add-repository contrib\
    && apt-get update
```

Try this.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -3):

Encountered the same issue and applied @Laurenz Albe's fix but I would get an authentication error on my user for the database, because of encryption strategy change.

So instead of replacing `scram-sha-256` with `md5`, replace it with `trust` in `pg_hba.conf`

Comment: replacing it with `trust` makes your postgresql doesn't even need authentication to get in. I think it is a bad approach

Comment: **DO NOT DO THIS!** `trust` authentication disables authentication.

Comment: i know this is not safe and all but this was the only method that worked for me. (still not safe)