# Forcing docker to use linux/amd64 platform by default on macOS

Tags: docker, multiplatform, apple-silicon

Current beta version of docker requires you to specify a `--platform=linux/amd64` each time you need to `build` or `run` an amd64 image/container.

The documentation mentions

> When running an image with multi-architecture support, docker will *automatically* select an image variant which matches your OS and architecture.

The documentation does not specify a way to alter this *automatic* behaviour using env variables. It seems to ignore both BUILDPLATFORM and TARGETPLATFORM.

Is there any other way to force `docker` to run all `build` and `run` commands with a platform `linux/amd64` instead of `linux/arm64/v8` by default on macOS running on apple-silicon?

Answer (score 334, accepted):

You can set the environment variable `DOCKER_DEFAULT_PLATFORM`:

```bash
export DOCKER_DEFAULT_PLATFORM=linux/amd64
```

Comment: This was introduced in v19.03.0 in 03/2019. I do not understand how I missed that.

Comment: This is great and it works, but i've also found I need to _unset_ it when creating clusters with `kind`. 
If you get errors like `docker: Cannot overwrite digest sha256:...`, try unsetting the `DOCKER_DEFAULT_PLATFORM` var.

Comment: is it possible to configure this option within a docker configuration file rather than a shell environment?

Comment: The link provided by @kctang is broken.  Here is one that works: https://blog.driftingruby.com/articles/2022/04/09/docker-builds-are-slow-on-m1.html

Answer (score 256):

Docker images built with *Apple Silicon* (or another **ARM64** based architecture) can create issues when deploying the images to a *Linux* or *Windows* based **AMD64* environment (e.g. *AWS EC2*, *ECS*, etc.). For example, you may try to upload your docker image made on the *M1* chip to an *AWS ECR* repository and it fails to run.  Therefore, you need a way to build **AMD64** based images on the **ARM64** architecture, whether it's using *Docker* build (for individual images) or `docker-compose` build (e.g. for multi-image apps running in a *docker compose* network).

For building single docker images:
Set your environment variable using the command line or modifying your `.bashrc` or `.zshenv` file as suggested in the accepted answer.

```bash
export DOCKER_DEFAULT_PLATFORM=linux/amd64
```

Alternatively, in the `Dockerfile`, include the following flag in the `FROM` command (for a multi-stage `Dockerfile` build, the flag is only needed for the first stage):

```yaml
FROM --platform=linux/amd64 python:3.7-alpine
```

For building images as part of a `docker-compose` build, include the `platform: linux/amd64` for each service. For example:

```yaml
  services:  
    frontend:  
      platform: linux/amd64
      build: frontend  
      ports:
        - 80:80  
      depends_on:
        - backend  
    backend:  
      platform: linux/amd64
      build: backend
```

Comment: What is the source of the "issues"? You mean like accidentally running ARM image on AMD64 platforms? Is it even possible?

Comment: I prefer this solution (I'm using docker-compose) over the accepted answer of setting env variable on the host OS

Comment: This works great. I'm using docker-compose to build linux/amd64 applications on a M1 MacBook Pro.

Comment: This is pretty old, but this points to the best option IMO, i chose to keep `platform` in `docker-compose.yaml` but adding `--platform=linux/amd64` do the `FROM` section of `DockerFile` seemed to be the best fix.

Comment: I prefer putting this in the `docker-compose.yml` file as well. This saved me. Thanks a lot!

Comment: will it work for docker-compose v3 files?

Answer (score 53):

You don't need to export the env variable as mentioned in one of the answers, you can run it as part of the command a single time by doing:

```bash
DOCKER_DEFAULT_PLATFORM=linux/amd64 docker-compose build
```

Keep in mind that if you've already downloaded the image for a different platform, docker will keep using that image no matter what platform you specify as your default, you would delete the image using `docker image rm your_img` first to fix that.

Comment: mind that if you system requires sudo to run docker, you have to put the PLATFORM into the sudo, note before that.
Correct example: `sudo DOCKER_DEFAULT_PLATFORM=linux/amd64 docker run --gpus all --shm-size 1g -p 8080:80 ghcr.io/huggingface/text-generation-inference:1.1.0`

Perhaps that is obvious, but some script kiddies can appreciate.

Comment: best solution when using compose ty

Answer (score 21):

You can use `buildx` (*mobi*) which suipport *cli* for platform.

```bash
docker buildx build --platform linux/amd64 .
```

Comment: Here is my Debian ARM docker build https://github.com/aem-design/docker-tini/blob/debian-arm/build.ps1 and here is the pipeline https://github.com/aem-design/docker-tini/blob/debian-arm/.github/workflows/build.yml. Its used here https://github.com/aem-design/docker-oracle-jdk/blob/jdk8-arm/Dockerfile.

Comment: Well buildx is an extra addition to docker hence ive mentioned it. But for Docker as is the docs on ENV variables are here https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cli/#environment-variables and they seem to be clear and to the point without any snark remarks.

Answer (score 13):

you can set

```
export DOCKER_DEFAULT_PLATFORM=linux/amd64
```

in a .zshrc file for Mac M1

Answer (score 4):

You can add in your `docker-compose.yaml`:

```yaml
services:
  service_name:
    environment:
      - DOCKER_DEFAULT_PLATFORM=linux/amd64
```

Comment: That doesnt really work for me. I think the "platform" is the way to go.

Comment: This would work for docker-in-docker. Not clear otherwise how this variable would be made available to the system docker daemon

Comment: I just tried this and it had no effect.

Answer (score 2):

Add this snipped to your ~/.zshrc and ~/.bashrc. It allows you not to repeat the flag anytime you perform a docker run command:

```
# useful only for Mac OS Silicon M1, 
# still working but useless for the other platforms
docker() {
  if [[ `uname -m` == "arm64" ]] && [[ "$1" == "run" || "$1" == "build" ]]; then
     /usr/local/bin/docker "$1" --platform linux/amd64 "${@:2}"
  else
     /usr/local/bin/docker "$@"
  fi
}
```