# docker-compose up issue Using Docker Apple M1

Tags: docker

I am really not familiar with docker, but I'm using docker to run a web app, which uses prisma/nexus

When I try to compose up, I get this error:

```
 Error: Unknown binaryTarget linux-arm-openssl-undefined and no custom binaries were provided
```

Can someone tell me what this error means, and how can I solve it? I think it has to do with the fact that docker doesn't support the OS that I'm working on, but I'm not entirely sure.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Docker image run in m1 processor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66456627/docker-image-run-in-m1-processor)

Answer (score 12):

Undefined means you don't have openssl installed in the container. You can get correct binary target name by installing openssl. Add this to Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:16-slim
RUN apt-get -qy update && apt-get -qy install openssl
```

Answer from here https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/861#issuecomment-881992292

Comment: This is the right answer. Installing Prisma on `alpine` is broken no matter what packages you install with `apk`. Using `slim` and installing `openssl` seems to fix it.

Answer (score 10):

From [the official docs](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/query-engine#overview),

> Prisma Client consists of three major components.
>
> - JavaScript client library
> - TypeScript type definitions
> - A query engine (in the form of **binary file**)

While the generated code is cross platform (this is javascript), the `query engine` is not.

When you run the `prisma generate` command, prisma seems to uses the `query engine`, but it needs to find the proper binary for the current platform [otherwise it throws an error](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/search?q=Unknown+binaryTarget).

The problem is for some reason I cannot explain (because I am having the same problem) the platform within the docker is not recognized as a [supported platform one](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/blob/01af9a9d026562162c158cafe8608fa77ad6bdab/src/packages/sdk/src/getGenerators.ts#L472-L488).

My guess is either docker is providing the wrong platform or there is a bug in prisma at some point, the error message `linux-arm-openssl-undefined`  with `undefined`in it could possibly be a clue of the problem.

Solution: Right now: **I plan running my images on an x86 computer** the time for this issue to be fixed. The latest docker 3 RC2 (released 5 days ago) did not help neither.

Note that you can specify binaryTargets into the `schema.prisma` file.

```
generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
  binaryTargets = ["debian-openssl-1.1.x"]
}
```

But for some reason, and even if I am building my docker image on top of a debian, this does not work. Prisma seems to recognize I am on `linux-arm` but is unable to associate a binaryTarget to. Also… is this platform really accurate ? Is docker running an linux arm under the hood or an x86 debian under rosetta ? I've no idea.

[EDIT]
node images are Multi-Arch, meaning

```
FROM node:15.12.0-buster-slim AS builder
```

Will pick the linux architecture for my host platform (linux/arm64/v8)
It seems we can actually [build for x86 on m1 using buildx experimental feature according to this post](https://blog.jaimyn.dev/how-to-build-multi-architecture-docker-images-on-an-m1-mac/)

Answer (score 2):

This can also mean that the image you're using in your *Dockerfile* (FROM **node:16-alpine** for example) are NOT available for **ARM**.

Most (if not all) images are available for **x86** [x86_64|amd64] architecture, but not all of them are available for **ARM**. You can check this in the image repository (ex.: https://hub.docker.com)

As you're building your image on your M1 Mac (with an **ARM** CPU) Docker guesses that you want an image built for **ARM**. That may be your case.

But for the OP I think this is probably not the case and he/she is targeting the built image to be run remotely in a cloud Linux server, which as of today are mostly **x86** [x86_64|amd64] machines.

If that's your scenario and you want images to be built for **x86** [x86_64|amd64] instead, you can specify the architecture in your *Dockerfile* **FROM** entry (or entries for multi-stage) and add them an argument specifying the architecture.

So, instead of

```
FROM node:16-alpine
```

do this

```
FROM --platform=linux/amd64 node:16-alpine
```

note: make sure to replace **ALL** entries if your *Dockerfile* is multi-stage (i.e.: has many **FROM** entries)

This will make the image to be built and target **x86** instead of ARM despite what CPU your M1 Mac has, which I think it was OP's goal.

- The built image will be compatible and will run at native speed in target x86 servers
- You can still run these images locally thru Docker for Mac via Rosetta2 x86 emulation (although somewhat slower) on your M1 Mac for Development or Debugging/Diagnostics purposes.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue when using `node:alpine`. First I tried to install manually openssl with `apk add openssl` but there were still some other issues raising.

I managed to solve it by switching to `node:lts` and adding to my Dockerfile `RUN apt-get -qy update && apt-get -qy install openssl`

Comment: Thanks this solution worked for me even though I am running a Macbook Air M1.
Changing `alpine` to `lts`and `apk` to `apt-get` fixed the issue.

Comment: Glad to hear it ! I am on a Macbook M1 as well

Answer (score 1):

Change the your base image from alpine to node this should fix the issue you are facing on M1. More information on this thread [thread](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/775)

Answer (score 0):

For me what works was mixed with some answers below.

For the container that was installing and generating Prisma I made this change:

```
# FROM node:fermium-alpine3.16 AS deps
FROM node:16-slim AS deps
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y openssl libssl-dev
```

And for the container that runs, I made it:

```
# FROM node:fermium-alpine3.16 AS runner
FROM --platform=linux/amd64 node:fermium-alpine3.16 AS runner
```

Thanks, everyone for the answers. I hope it helps someone else.