# Docker on Mac M1 gives: "The requested image's platform (linux/amd64) does not match the detected host platform"

Tags: docker, docker-compose, arm, apple-m1

I want to run a docker container for `Ganache` on my MacBook M1, but get the following error:

```
The requested image's platform (linux/amd64) does not match the detected host platform (linux/arm64/v8) and no specific platform was requested
```

After this line nothing else will happen anymore and the whole process is stuck, although the qemu-system-aarch64 is running on 100% CPU according to Activity Monitor until I press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

My docker-files come from [this repository](https://github.com/unlock-protocol/unlock/blob/master/docker/docker-compose.override.yml). After running into the same issues there I tried to isolate the root cause and came up with the smallest setup that will run into the same error.

This is the output of `docker-compose up --build`:

```
Building ganache
Sending build context to Docker daemon  196.6kB
Step 1/17 : FROM trufflesuite/ganache-cli:v6.9.1
 ---> 40b011a5f8e5
Step 2/17 : LABEL Unlock <ops@unlock-protocol.com>
 ---> Using cache
 ---> aad8a72dac4e
Step 3/17 : RUN apk add --no-cache git openssh bash
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 4ca6312438bd
Step 4/17 : RUN apk add --no-cache   python   python-dev   py-pip   build-base   && pip install virtualenv
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 0be290f541ed
Step 5/17 : RUN npm install -g npm@6.4.1
 ---> Using cache
 ---> d906d229a768
Step 6/17 : RUN npm install -g yarn
 ---> [Warning] The requested image's platform (linux/amd64) does not match the detected host platform (linux/arm64/v8) and no specific platform was requested
 ---> Running in 991c1d804fdf
```

**docker-compose.yml:**

```
version: '3.2'
services:
  ganache:
    restart: always
    build:
      context: ./development
      dockerfile: ganache.dockerfile
    env_file: ../.env.dev.local
    ports:
      - 8545:8545

  ganache-standup:
    image: ganache-standup
    build:
      context: ./development
      dockerfile: ganache.dockerfile
    env_file: ../.env.dev.local
    entrypoint: ['node', '/standup/prepare-ganache-for-unlock.js']
    depends_on:
      - ganache
```

**ganache.dockerfile:**

The ganache.dockerfile can be found [here](https://github.com/unlock-protocol/unlock/blob/master/docker/development/ganache.dockerfile).

Running the whole project on an older iMac with Intel-processor works fine.

Comment: can you run `hello-world` docker image?

Comment: It really looks like the image you're trying to use isnt available for arm architecture which is the one for the M1 MAC. Try running `docker run ubuntu:latest echo hello world` instead. this image comes with linux/arm64/v8 architcture comapred to v5 in `hello-world:linux` (which is the only one that comes with any dort of arm support)

Comment: Hello World works, yes. But so many other docker images not that we are using in the company. I am only person with M1 :(

Comment: As of a while ago, Docker on an M1 can run linux/amd64 images

Answer (score 58):

If you're planning to run the image in your laptop, you need to build it for the cpu architecture of that particular machine. You can provide the `--platform` option to docker build (or even to `docker-compose`) to define the target platform you want to build the image for.

For example:

```
docker build --platform linux/arm64  .
```

Comment: add "buildx" and run like:

$ docker buildx build --platform linux/amd64 .

Comment: for those using docker compose, add the `platform: linux/amd64` option to the affected images in your `docker-compose.yml`

Answer (score 47):

On M1 MacBook Pro, I've had success using `docker run --platform linux/amd64`

**Example**

```
docker run --platform linux/amd64 node
```

Comment: Note that `node` should be replaced with the appropriate image name. Otherwise it'll be pulling and running `node` rather than the desired image.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Perhaps you meant `arm64` or this solution works for specific images only.

Comment: This worked for me with pydicom/dicom image.  Thank you!

Comment: Did not work for me. Used following command on M1:
docker run --platform linux/amd64 -p 4000:4000 in28min/hello-world-python:0.0.1.RELEASE

Comment: This example is just for the node image and is run to an `amd64` image on `arm64` hardware. Not all images appear to support this.

Comment: I don't this works anymore this is 2023 already outdated answer

Comment: It still works fine.

`❯ docker run --platform linux/amd64 node --version`
`v19.7.0`

Comment: for docker-compose, use `platform: linux/amd64`

Answer (score 30):

With docker-compose you also have the `platform` option.

```
version: "2.4"
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:7.1.1
    hostname: zookeeper
    container_name: zookeeper
    platform: linux/amd64
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
```

Answer (score 8):

We were facing this issue with the localstack image.

Below is the snippet from the docker-compose.yml

```
localstack:
    container_name: "${LOCALSTACK_DOCKER_NAME-localstack_main}"
    image: localstack/localstack:1.2.0
    ports:
      - "4566:4566"
    environment:
      - DOCKER_HOST=unix:///var/run/docker.sock
```

One of the developers working with M1 chipset on Mac was getting this issue.

So there are few approaches

1. Add `platform: linux/amd64` in the image declaration in docker-compose.yml
2. Run this command `export DOCKER_DEFAULT_PLATFORM=linux/amd64` before running the docker-compose.yml
3. Best is to refer the architecture specific image. For e.g. in our case, we used `image: localstack/localstack:1.2.0-amd64`

**Reference**
https://hub.docker.com/layers/localstack/localstack/1.2.0-amd64/images/sha256-474600686aa98e8c79df96a9e7e5f689487c3a624ba8e464a0b6c3f45985cbcd?context=explore

Answer (score 4):

Build the image by passing the list of architecture

Try this:

```
docker buildx build --platform linux/amd64,linux/arm64,linux/arm/v7 -t username/demo:latest --push .
```

Note: ensure to place "." at the end

Comment: This solved my issue, what does the buildx do?

Comment: See https://www.docker.com/blog/multi-arch-images/

Answer (score 2):

You should have the docker buildx installed. If you don't have the docker-desktop you can download the binary buildx from github: https://github.com/docker/buildx/

After installation you can build your image like Theofilos Papapanagiotou said

<downloaded_path>/buildx --platform linux/amd64 ...

Answer (score 1):

Use colima. then you'll be able to run x86/64 only images on your M1/M2 Mac as well

```
brew install colima
colima start --memory 4 --arch x86_64
docker run [image name you want to run]
```

That's it. it's quite simple. https://github.com/abiosoft/colima

Comment: Looks rather messy. What does it do behind the scene?

Comment: it's just a lightweight container runtime like Docker Desktop. You can 
check out if you're interested https://github.com/abiosoft/colima

btw, Docker Desktop team is trying to add new feat which is using Rosetta for old arch images, it doesn't work well yet but we'll be able to run x86/64 images soon i reckon

Answer (score -1):

You might need to run

```
docker run --rm --privileged multiarch/qemu-user-static --reset -p yes
```

in order to register foreign file formats with the kernel.

Comment: Tried this one at M1 but it doesn't work for me :(

Comment: Maybe this does not apply for M1.
I based this on the steps needed for x86, see here https://www.stereolabs.com/docs/docker/building-arm-container-on-x86/

There, there is the pre-requisite of installing `qemu binfmt-support qemu-user-static`