# Docker local Nexus responded `Empty reply from server` when Curl

Tags: docker, nexus, nexus3

I tried setup a local Nexus using Docker as per the instruction in https://hub.docker.com/r/sonatype/nexus3/

I run the below and seems successful

```
docker run -d -p 8081:8081 --name nexus sonatype/nexus3
```

But when I `curl http://localhost:8081/`
It state

```
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

Did I miss anything?

**UPDATE**

Apparently when I run `docker logs -f nexus`

It shows

```
java.io.IOException: Function not implemented
    at sun.nio.fs.LinuxWatchService.<init>(LinuxWatchService.java:64)
    at sun.nio.fs.LinuxFileSystem.newWatchService(LinuxFileSystem.java:47)
    at com.install4j.runtime.launcher.FullLauncherHelper.watchDirectory(FullLauncherHelper.java:52)
    at com.install4j.runtime.launcher.util.SingleInstance.createStartupListener(SingleInstance.java:108)
    at com.install4j.runtime.launcher.util.SingleInstance.check(SingleInstance.java:95)
    at com.install4j.runtime.launcher.util.SingleInstance.checkForCurrentLauncher(SingleInstance.java:31)
    at com.install4j.runtime.launcher.UnixLauncher.checkSingleInstance(UnixLauncher.java:88)
    at com.install4j.runtime.launcher.UnixLauncher.main(UnixLauncher.java:67)
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00000040a5fe0678, pid=1, tid=0x00000040a5fe1700
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (8.0_282-b08) (build 1.8.0_282-b08)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (25.282-b08 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  0x00000040a5fe0678
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /opt/sonatype/nexus/hs_err_pid1.log
Compiled method (c1)    5136  467       3       org.apache.felix.resolver.util.OpenHashMap::mix (12 bytes)
 total in heap  [0x000000400cf73f10,0x000000400cf74208] = 760
 relocation     [0x000000400cf74038,0x000000400cf74060] = 40
 main code      [0x000000400cf74060,0x000000400cf74120] = 192
 stub code      [0x000000400cf74120,0x000000400cf741b0] = 144
 oops           [0x000000400cf741b0,0x000000400cf741b8] = 8
 metadata       [0x000000400cf741b8,0x000000400cf741c0] = 8
 scopes data    [0x000000400cf741c0,0x000000400cf741d0] = 16
 scopes pcs     [0x000000400cf741d0,0x000000400cf74200] = 48
 dependencies   [0x000000400cf74200,0x000000400cf74208] = 8
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   https://bugzilla.redhat.com/enter_bug.cgi?product=Red%20Hat%20Enterprise%20Linux%208&component=java-1.8.0-openjdk
#
qemu: uncaught target signal 6 (Aborted) - core dumpe
```

**UPDATE**

When trying on the MacbookPro Intel machine, all works fine. The issue happens on my MacbookPro M1.

I tried `export DOCKER_DEFAULT_PLATFORM=linux/amd64` as per https://stackoverflow.com/a/66900911/3286489, issue still persist

Answer (score 3):

The sonatype nexus 3 compatibility issues persist.
We can use
https://hub.docker.com/r/klo2k/nexus3
for now

```
docker run -d -p 8081:8081 --name nexus klo2k/nexus3
```