# x86 Docker Image on ARM

Tags: docker

I have a Docker image that was built and uploaded to Amazon ECR by a x86 machine.

I'm trying to run this image on an ARM machine; however, I'm getting the following:

```
$sudo docker run 1b3ed34937e8

WARNING: The requested image's platform (linux/amd64) does not match the detected host platform (linux/arm64/v8) and no specific platform was requested
standard_init_linux.go:228: exec user process caused: exec format error
```

Do I need to rebuild this image? Is it possible to rebuild with only an image and not a dockerfile?

Comment: Can you run `uname -m` and post the output?

Comment: aarch64 is the output

Answer (score 12):

You can also use the emulation-layer built into docker:

```
docker run --platform linux/amd64 {imagename}
```

Since this is based on emulation it will not be as performant as running the container using the host architecture.

Comment: How shall I run a docker-compose which has many x86 docker containers. 
I am trying to run that on ARM architecture.

Comment: Apparently you can use the environment variable `DOCKER_DEFAULT_PLATFORM` .

Try setting that environment variable in your shell session before starting the containers via your compose file:
```export DOCKER_DEFAULT_PLATFORM=linux/amd64```

For further information have a look at this SO-issue:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65612411/forcing-docker-to-use-linux-amd64-platform-by-default-on-macos

Answer (score 4):

You are trying to build x86 Docker images on a different architecture (ARM).

Rebuild the images on the Mac, or if you are still building the image on X86 you can set the target platform

```
docker buildx build --platform darwin/amd64 -t app .
```

Answer (score 1):

For future searchs, you can to install qemu emulation:

apt-get install qemu binfmt-support qemu-user-static

ref.: https://www.stereolabs.com/docs/docker/building-arm-container-on-x86/