# Is there a way to force Docker to always use certain platform/arch?

Tags: docker, apple-m1

With the propagation of Apple M1 chips, we've encountered a problem. We are using Docker to build images to deploy our software, but we discovered that some images which are built from Dockerfiles like this:

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04 as base
...
```

are no longer working in our infrastructure. Those are images built on M1 machines, because, as it turns out, Ubuntu helpfully has a multiplatform image, and Docker chooses `arm` platform for M1 builds, while our deployment infrastructure, of course, remains on `amd64`.

We could go and edit every single Dockerfile to use

```
FROM --platform=linux/amd64 ubuntu:20.04 as base
```

and that fixes the problem, but this is very annoying, we have a lot of Dockerfiles. Is there some way to force Docker to always use `amd64` platform for multiplatform images on the build side?
One of the advantages of Docker has been - no matter where you build it, you get the predictable image. Now this assumption is broken, we'd like to restore it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66900911/9095551

Comment: I'd recommend building multi platform images rather than forcing the arm users to run amd64 images. See buildx for how docker has simplified this. Also your servers should be running builds from controlled CI systems, not developer laptops.

Comment: We don't need multi-platform images, why would we waste time and diskspace building them?

Comment: You seem to have multiple platforms in your organization. Otherwise, this question doesn't make sense. Why not support those other platforms?

Comment: @BMitch we have multiple developer platforms, but single deployment platforms - that's where the images are deployed. We want to enable developers on M1 platforms build images that can be deployed on Intel deployment platform.