# I can't use Tensorflow on M1 macbook + Lima(Intel on ARM)

Tags: docker, tensorflow, apple-m1

I have created an Intel x86-64 virtual environment on my M1 macbook using Lima, and I am trying to run tensorflow with a docker container there, but it does not work with the following error.

> 2022-04-22 07:41:51.408085: F
> tensorflow/core/lib/monitoring/sampler.cc:42] Check failed:
> bucket_limits_[i] > bucket_limits_[i - 1] (4.17216e-152 vs. 10)

I have successfully installed tensorflow.
When I check with limactl list, ARCH is correctly set to x86_64.

I checked and it seems to be an error when trying to run ensorflow on M1 mac. Is it not possible to run it on x86-64 virtual environment?
How can this be resolved?

Answer (score 0):

By default it's trying to run on architecture arm64, if you want to run it on amd64 you have to configure it. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69636473/15224199)