# Docker Fails When Building on M1 Macs (exec /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: exec format error)

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I got a legacy project running with `docker-compose`. A year ago it was starting with the configuration below.

Now it's throwing an error:

```
exec /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: exec format error
```

I would like to run the container with the CMD configuration. I found in the web to add `#!/bin/bash` is required to avoid this error, which I added to the Dockerfile.

There is no custom `docker-entrypoint.sh` defined. As far as I understand the docs there needs to be either an entrypoint or a command.

> The main purpose of a CMD is to provide defaults for an executing
> container. These defaults can include an executable, or they can omit
> the executable, in which case you must specify an ENTRYPOINT
> instruction as well.

## Dockerfile

```
#!/bin/bash

#nodejs
FROM node:11.15
ENV NODE_VERSION 11.15

#app directory
WORKDIR ./

#mongodb tools
RUN wget -qO - https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-5.0.asc | apt-key add -
RUN echo "deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/debian buster/mongodb-org/5.0 main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-5.0.list
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y mongodb

RUN apt-get install nano

#nodejs packages
# A wildcard is used to ensure both package.json AND package-lock.json are copied
# where available (npm@5+)
COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install --ignore-scripts sharp
RUN npm install --only=production

COPY . .

RUN mkdir -p /logs/

# wait for mongoDB launch
ADD https://github.com/ufoscout/docker-compose-wait/releases/download/2.5.1/wait /wait
RUN chmod +x /wait

#port of the app
EXPOSE 8080

CMD /wait && npm run dockerServer
```

### Docker Compose

```
version: "3"
services:
    watchtower:
        container_name: watchtower
        image: v2tec/watchtower
        env_file:
             - watchtower.env
        volumes:
            - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
            - /root/.docker/config.json:/config.json
        command: --interval 30
        restart: always
    mongo:
        container_name: mongo
        ports:
            - '27017:27017'
        volumes:
            - '/temp/im/docker/mongo/data:/data/db'
            - '/temp/im/docker/backup:/data/backup'
        image: mongo
        restart: always
    core:
        container_name: core
        ports:
            - '8080:8080'
        env_file:
            - core.env
        depends_on:
            - "mongo"
        volumes:
            - '/temp/im/docker/logs:/data/logs'
            - '/temp/im/docker/backup:/data/backup'
        image: index.docker.io/regname/core:beta
        logging:
            driver: "json-file"
            options:
                max-file: '5'
                max-size: '10m'
        restart: always
```

EDIT: I changed the title to make it better discoverable.

Comment: What CPU architecture is your host; are you on an M1 Mac?  It looks like you're downloading and installing a Rust binary from a GitHub repository, does it have any shared-library dependencies you're missing?  Can you `docker-compose run core sh` to get a debugging shell inside a new container and poke around (it is informative if you can't)?

Comment: (I'd suggest using CMD and not ENTRYPOINT here is preferable, in part because it makes that `docker-compose run` line straightforward.  The "shebang" line won't make a difference here and is incorrect; it only would do something if you were trying to directly run `./Dockerfile` as a command, and the Dockerfile isn't a shell script.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Forcing docker to use linux/amd64 platform by default on macOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65612411/forcing-docker-to-use-linux-amd64-platform-by-default-on-macos)

Answer (score 140, accepted):

Try to change `FROM`:

```
FROM --platform=linux/amd64 node:11.15
```

There is a good [explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69636473/17650498).

Comment: That did the trick. Googling it revealed it is a problem with Mac M1 chips and building docker images.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65612411/forcing-docker-to-use-linux-amd64-platform-by-default-on-macos

Comment: This helped me fix a crash loop failure on my K8s cluster as well. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, other options for the platform tag though here: https://docs.docker.com/build/guide/multi-platform/#build-using-emulation

Answer (score 14):

Building docker image with the following also works. `docker build --platform=linux/amd64 -t <image:tag>`