# Docker container exits immediately after running the container

Tags: angular, docker, dockerfile, containers

I have an angular 17 project and I want to dockerize it. I already build my image and when I tried to run the container using `docker run -dit --name <container name> <imagename>` but the container exits immediately after that. When I run `docker ps` my container doesn't appear.

Dockerfile:

```
# Use node image as builder
FROM node:18.14 AS builder

# Set working directory in the container
WORKDIR /app

# Copy package.json and package-lock.json to the container
COPY package.json package-lock.json ./

# Install dependencies
RUN npm install

# Copy the rest of the application code
COPY . .

# Build the application
RUN npm run build --prod

# Use nginx image for serving the application
FROM nginx:latest

# Copy built application files from builder stage to nginx directory
COPY --from=builder /app/dist/project /usr/share/nginx/html

# Expose port 80 for nginx
EXPOSE 80

# Start nginx in foreground
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

And I noticed that my image cannot be analyzed in docker desktop as shown in this screenshot:
[Docker Desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rJOee.png)

Comment: I believe `nginx -g` merely sets a global configuration directive.  It does not actually run nginx.

Comment: If you run the container without the `-d` option, what shows up on its output?  You should not need the `EXPOSE` or `CMD` lines in this particular Dockerfile (you're repeating what's already in the `nginx` image) and you shouldn't need `-i` or `-t` options to run the container, but these probably aren't related to the actual problem.

Comment: this is the error when I run the container without -d

Comment: exec /docker-entrypoint.sh: exec format error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned in comment `exec /docker-entrypoint.sh: exec format error` is the real problem to solve.
Can you come up with a minimal, reproducible example? As an example, this is working locally for me

```
# Use node image as builder
FROM node:18.14 AS builder

# Set working directory in the container
WORKDIR /app

# (pretend to) Build the application
RUN echo "Hello world" > out.txt

# Use nginx image for serving the application
FROM nginx:latest

# Copy built application files from builder stage to nginx directory
COPY --from=builder /app/ /usr/share/nginx/html
```

It's likely related to processor architecture differences, see [Docker Fails When Building on M1 Macs (exec /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: exec format error)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73398714/docker-fails-when-building-on-m1-macs-exec-usr-local-bin-docker-entrypoint-sh) and https://docs.docker.com/build/guide/multi-platform/

If you're building an image locally and running it elsewhere, this may well be the solution - https://stackoverflow.com/a/69636473/131391

If you're building and running locally, then I would first make sure you can simply run the mentioned base images before writing the Dockerfile. e.g. `docker run nginx:latest`