# PostgreSQL downgrade password encryption from SCRAM to md5

Tags: postgresql, md5, psql, password-encryption, postgresql-13

I need to downgrade password encryption for user *postgres* from *scram-sha-265* to *md5*.

I've tried modifying *pg_hba.conf* and *postgresql.conf* files changing password encryption from *scram-sha-256* to *md5* but after that I was unable to connect to the database.

I'm using PostgreSQL 13 and PgAdmin 4 v5.

Thanks for any help and suggestion!

PS: I have to do this because RStudio can't manage connections with scram authentication.

Comment: What error did you get? What did the log file say?

Comment: The error is *Error in postgresqlNewConnection(drv, ...) : 
  RS-DBI driver: (could not connect postgres@127.0.0.1:5432 on dbname "progetto_bd": SCRAM authentication requires libpq version 10 or above
)*

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the library version is above 10

Comment: But the error message is pretty sure it is not.  I think we can go with the error message here.  I have seen it a lot, and never known it to be wrong.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I solved following these steps:

Change password_encryption to `md5` in file *postgresql.conf*

Change the first 3 occurrences of `scram-sha-256` to `trust` in file *pg_hba.conf*

```
# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     trust
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 trust
```

Restart postgresql service

Execute `psql -U postgres` (you won't be asked for password)

Change password with command `\password username`

Change the first 3 occurrences of `trust` to `md5` in file *pg_hba.conf*

```
# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     md5
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
```

Restart postgresql service

Answer (score 3):

You need to reload the database, then set the user's password again (probably using a superuser account), so that the user has an MD5-hashed password again. Connect to the database as superuser with `psql`, then:

```
SELECT pg_reload_conf();

-- to verify the settings are like you want:

SHOW password_encryption;
SELECT * FROM pg_hba_file_rules();

-- change the password

\password myuser
```

Comment: Can you be more precise? Thanks :)

Comment: I have extended my answer.

Comment: thank you for the answer. I tried these lines one by one after logging in to psql, but nothing gets return to me, except for "\password myuser". Is that normal? Also for "myuser", it tells me role "myuser" does not exist; so I tried "postgresql" still not working... Any advice please?

Comment: @Helene You forgot the semicolons.