# Python psycopg2 SCRAM authentication

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I'm trying to run a python application that uses psycopg2-binary==2.9.1, but I'm hitting this  error:

```
psycopg2.OperationalError: SCRAM authentication requires libpq version 10 or above
```

When I check the version of libpq installed, it suggests I have 12.8:

```
sudo dpkg -l | grep libpq
ii  libpq5:arm64                       12.8-0ubuntu0.20.04.1             arm64        PostgreSQL C client library
```

I searched around and saw some recommendations to switch off scram authentication, so I changed authentication to md5 in pg_hba.conf and postgresql.conf and then reloaded config (and restarted my database).

I'm still getting this problem. Does anyone know what is wrong ? Thanks in advance

Comment: How did you compile psycopg2?  Did the compilation use that version of libpq or a different one?

Comment: You can strace it and see what libpq file (if any) it is actually opening.

Comment: @jjanes I gave that a try and I suspect  psycopg2-binary itself has the libpq library (I'm using pyinstaller):

venv$ find . | grep libpq
./lib/python3.8/site-packages/psycopg2_binary.libs/libpq-c98caf99.so.5.9

Comment: That's weird.  For me it has 'libpq-6f24e430.so.5.13'.  What if you do -U for pip?  Or uninstall and reinstall?

Comment: I'm seeing the same on another server I am running as well:
./venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psycopg2_binary.libs/libpq-6f24e430.so.5.13

I wonder if this is a bad distribution for ubuntu 20.0

Answer (score 12):

I'm using apple silicon (M1 Pro).

In my environment (python debian image on docker), the solution is to upgrade libpq and install build tools, then build psycopg2-binary from source.

ubuntu example code:

```sh
sudo apt update -y && sudo apt install -y build-essential libpq-dev
pip install psycopg2-binary --no-binary psycopg2-binary
```

Comment: Why not just `pip install psycopg2` instead? That's the no binary version of the package, I believe?

Answer (score 5):

I have the same issue with my arm64 build.
When I build a Docker Container based on Python3 (Debian).
If I build for arm64 I see it will install libpq version 9

```
WARNING: The requested image's platform (linux/arm64) does not match the detected host platform (linux/amd64) and no specific platform was requested
Python 3.10.0 (default, Nov 18 2021, 00:02:14) [GCC 10.2.1 20210110] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import psycopg2 
>>> print(psycopg2.__libpq_version__)
90623
>>> print(psycopg2.extensions.libpq_version())
90623
>>>
```

but if I build the exact same dockerfile on a amd64 CPU i got a different version installed.

```
Python 3.10.0 (default, Nov 17 2021, 15:26:39) [GCC 10.2.1 20210110] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import psycopg2
>>> print(psycopg2.__libpq_version__)
130003
>>> print(psycopg2.extensions.libpq_version())
130003
```

I did also tried with `python:3-alpine` for arm64 and get a much better result.

```
WARNING: The requested image's platform (linux/arm64) does not match the detected host platform (linux/amd64) and no specific platform was requested
/src # python
Python 3.10.0 (default, Nov 30 2021, 00:28:27) [GCC 10.3.1 20211027] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import psycopg2
>>> print(psycopg2.__libpq_version__)
140001
>>> print(psycopg2.extensions.libpq_version())
140001
>>>
```

So I guess the issue is the repo that Debian/Ubuntu are using.
Maybe you should open a ticket with Debian and Ubuntu to update that package for Postgresql-client for arm64.

Answer (score 4):

This is now properly handled by the new version of psycopg2 https://github.com/psycopg/psycopg2/releases/tag/2.9.6

Comment: You're right, worked for me!

Comment: This worked for me for running my code in an AWS lambda function with python 3.9 on arm64 with psycopg2-binary==2.9.6.

Answer (score 1):

There must be a second copy of libpq on your machine, and psycopg is using that copy. Identify that file and remove or upgrade it. Perhaps that requires updating psycopg.

Comment: I looked at the wheel of psycopg-binary (which is the python package I’m using). For reasons unknown, version 2.9.1 had an old version of libpq. This was for Ubuntu 20.0 arm64

Comment: That was a good reminder

Answer (score 0):

If you are using docker to deploy your app, this worked for me

```
# FROM pypy:3.6-7.3.3-slim
FROM python:3.10
WORKDIR /usr/src/test_repo

    
COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip install --upgrade pip && pip install -r requirements.txt
RUN apt-get autoremove -y

RUN apt-get install -y libpq-dev gcc

RUN pip install psycopg2-binary --no-binary psycopg2-binary

COPY . .
EXPOSE 5001
ENTRYPOINT ["flask","run","--host=0.0.0.0","--port=5001"]
```