# connecting to PostgreSQL with psycopg2 on AWS gives error SCRAM authentication requires libpq version 10 or above

Tags: python, postgresql, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to access PostgreSQL on AWS using psycopg2 in Python.
The connect call fails with error message:

```
SCRAM authentication requires libpq version 10 or above
```

```
>>> c = psycopg2.connect(dbname="test", user="user", password="***", host="HOSTNAME")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 122, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
psycopg2.OperationalError: SCRAM authentication requires libpq version 10 or above
```

Checking the installed version of libpq using `yum list installed` looks as if a version above 10 is installed:

```
libpq.aarch64                    14.3-2.amzn2.0.2                    @amzn2extra-postgresql14
```

os is Amazon Linux 2
Python is Python 3.8.16

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Peter

Comment: How did you install `psycopg2` and what version of it are you using? Pretty sure this is issue of `psycopg2` not being linked to new enough version of `libpq`.

Comment: Just because you have a newer version doesn't mean it is the only version you have.  See what libpq is actually getting loaded.  Something like `strace python3 -c 'import psycopg2' 2>&1 | fgrep libpq` does it for me.

Comment: Yes, these were the right pointers Adrian Klaver and jjanes: actually installed was the Python package psycopg2-binary - obviously statically linked.
Something like this had just been beyond my expectations.
Thank you very much.

Comment: @PeterFankhänel - Did you figure out a way around this issue? I am seeing the same error from one of my Lambdas that is attempting to connect to a version 14 postgres database. I'm using `aws-psycopg2` which I'm sure is the culprit.

Comment: After installing a psycopg2-binary linked to the correct version of libpq it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Use `psycopg2-binary` package (**NOT** `psycopg2`)

```bash
pip install psycopg2-binary
```

Then import as usual in your code:

```py
import psycopg2
```

I had the same problem with the base image for AWS lambda `public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.9`, but this fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

`psycopg2-binary` did not solve the problem for me.

###### My use case

I ran into this problem with my AWS lambda function on arm64, python3.9 and psycopg2-binary==2.9.3:
Running code in a virtual environment (venv) locally as python module worked fine. But running it in a lambda function on AWS failed with the error.

###### My solution

- Solution 1: Changing the architecture from `arm64` to `x86_64` solved the problem
- Solution 2: Using `psycopg2-binary==2.9.6` solved the problem ([Props to this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75935123/6702598) )