# flask-react-aws recreate_db SCRAM auth error

Tags: docker, sqlalchemy, testdriven.io

In Getting Started, Part 1, Chapter 4, of Deploying a Flask and React Microservice to AWS ECS, when running

```
$ docker-compose exec api python manage.py recreate_db
```

Receiving the following error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) SCRAM authentication requires libpq version 10 or above
```

From reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62807717/how-can-i-solve-postgresql-scram-authentifcation-problem) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65612411/forcing-docker-to-use-linux-amd64-platform-by-default-on-macos/69636473#69636473) SO posts, and being on an Apple M1 Mac, I added `platform: linux/amd64` to the `api` service in `docker-compose.yml`, which got me past the error, albeit not sure if this is the correct solution in this case.