# SCRAM authentication requires libpq version 10 or above in google app engine flexible

Tags: postgresql, google-app-engine, flask-sqlalchemy

i am using
PostgreSQL 14 on app engine flexible
on standard with python version 3.8 it works fine but on flexible there's no support for python 3.8 and i get SCRAM authentication requires libpq version 10 or above is there anyway around this?

tried changing postgresql.conf file but that's only for that particular instance

Comment: You could use a service provider who provides less outdated software.

Comment: this might be related to an ARM based image while developing on your Mac with an M1 processor.

See other answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62807717/how-can-i-solve-postgresql-scram-authentication-problem