# Unable to connect to PostgreSQL server: SCRAM authentication requires libpq version 10 or above [adminer]

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, adminer

I am using adminer 4.8.1 running on MAMP. When I visit localhost:8888/adminer/ and try to login inside postgres db. I am getting `Unable to connect to PostgreSQL server: SCRAM authentication requires libpq version 10 or above`

I am on Macbook pro M1 chip. OS ventura 13.6.

I have tried all the solutions already existing in stackoverflow, internet etc., to change the `postgres.conf` `password encryption` from `scram-sha-256` to `md5`. Also editied `pg_hba.conf` changed the all method from `trust` to `md5`. restarted postgres service (postgresql@14).

when tried to connect using `psql -U postgres`. It asks me for password which I don't know what to do because `brew install postgresql@14` it never asked me for password. I typed lappy password and `password` , `root` etc., but no use.

Why I am doing this is because there is article to do (below) to above all steps. I am stuck at this (password for user postgres) `psql: error: connection to server on socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"` step.

After this step, when we logged inside the postgres db, Article suggested to do ALTER PASSWORD with new password query. Assuming, After this hope scram authentication error won't come

I want to use adminer because, this tool gives me edge interms of database management over pgadmin4.

P.S: Everything works fine with pgadmin 4, but I don't want to use pgadmin 4. I want to use adminer for my database activities

Kindly help! Been tinkering over this over 2 days till now

I have tried accepted solution over this question

[How can I solve Postgresql SCRAM authentication problem?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62807717/how-can-i-solve-postgresql-scram-authentication-problem)